# java object to Sha-256

Tags: java, hash, sha256

I'm trying to use Hash Function. I understand that I can digest string or bytes.  But, what is the input value when I use Object O for the input?

Object O has two int values, and toString() function

```
public Key(int arg1, int arg2) {
    super();
    this.a=arg1;
    this.b=arg2;
}


try{
    MessageDigest v1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    O.update(v1);
    v2_1 = BytesToHex(v1.digest());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MessageDigest` only works with bytes. It doesn't even accept `String`s. Just bytes.

These are the available update methods. You can see that all four of them only deal with bytes:

```
void update​(byte input);
void update​(byte[] input);
void update​(byte[] input, int offset, int len);
void update​(ByteBuffer input);
```

It's up to you to serialize objects into bytes using the procedure of your choice. `MessageDigest` doesn't handle it for you, nor does it have any convenience methods to assist in the process. It doesn't deal with anything except raw bytes.

Comment: Thanks!! if I update Message Diegest twice with different bytes, is it get mixed?

Comment: @choky7 no, the bytes don't get "mixed" - the bytes are appended. `update(new byte[] {1,2});` followed by `update(new byte[] {3,4});` has the same effect on the digest as calling ` `update(new byte[] {1,2,3,4});`